# Missing function header C++

Tags: c++

i am getting this error when i want to build my cpp file.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)   Win32Project1   d:\persoonlijk\documenten\2e leerjaar\c++\win32project1\win32project1\leerlinggegevens_hfst3.cpp    2

Here is the code i am using:

```
/*Hoofdstuk 3, Leerlinggegevens*/
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int lnr;
    string lnm;
    string oplnm;
    string klasm;
    //DECRALEREN

    cout << "Voer je leerlingnummer in: \n";
    cin >> lnr;


    cout << "Vul je naam in: \n";
    cin >> lnm;

    cout << "Vul je opleiding in: \n";
    cin >> oplnm;

    cout << "Vul je klas in: \n";
    cin >> klasm;

    cout << "Jouw ingevulde leerleerlinggegevens bestaan uit: \n" << "Leerling " << lnr << " met leerlingnummer " << lnm << "staat ingeschreven bij opleiding " << oplnm << " \n" << "Leerlingnummer " << lnr << " zit in klas " << klasm << endl;


    system("PAUSE");

}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: nothign wrong with the code, it compiles just fine: https://godbolt.org/g/lrR1tz

Comment: Same on Ideone, the code you posted compiles just fine.

Comment: Have you  shared leerlinggegevens_hfst3.cpp? Because that's what the error points at

Comment: Also, can you edit yourquestion including the compiler (and version) you are using?

Comment: @xaxxon That doesn't mean there's nothing wrong with the code. The [header for `system` is missing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system), for example.

Comment: Don't copy from the Error List, use the Output tab instead. The Error List is pretty rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine in Windows environment it seems.

In case you are running on Linux environment, but I am not quite sure whether  `system("PAUSE");`works over there or not. Even, this seems to me as non - portable code.

I would recommend you to use `cin.get()` or `getchar()` instead, to make it portable. If you want to more why I am saying so, you can go through this link: http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html

Answer (score 0):

The source code you posted compiles just fine with both Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 and gcc (tried on ideone.com).

The only way to get the C2447 compile error you are getting, with Visual C++, is to add a semi-colon (;) right after main():

> int main();
>   {

(but Visual Studio 2015 editor highlights the error, even before compiling the code).